# PNG buttons do not alight correctly

Tags: html, css, png

I have 6 png images that I am trying to align as buttons in one line.  All the buttons tend to align correctly expect for the last one.  I have margin-left:0px, so all the buttons stick together looking like a long tag.

During load time, if the page takes longer the last button loads fastest so loads and just goes all over the place.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. 99% of the time, for menus you should be using text links with an [image replacement method](http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/#phark). Just as tables should only be used for tabular data, images should only be used for semantically visual data.
2. Do the `<img>` tags have an explicit height and width? i.e. `<img src="#" height="100" width="60"/>`? If not, try giving them one. If this is not defined, the browser does not know the height and width of the image until it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try floating them left or right (depending on your layout) and or making them blocks:

.myimg { float:left; display:block; }